# Polymer 1.0 paper-card displays {{ }} binding variables as it is inside Angularjs ng-repeat - [Issue only in Chrome]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, polymer-1.0

I am very new to angularjs, i have done some experimental projects in Polymer 0.5, so new to Polymer 1.0 as well.

I am facing an issue like inside ng-repeat i want to display some paper-card.

> This issue is only on **Chrome browser**, In **Firefox** and **IE-edge** it is coming fine.

```
<paper-card heading="{{ team.name }}">

  <div class="card-content">Some content</div>
  <div class="card-actions">
    <paper-button>Some action</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

//--------------------------- HTML ----------

```
   <div class="row content">
    <div><h3>Teams  <img ng-show="loading" ng-src='images/loader2.gif' width="30px" height="30px"/></h3></div>
    <div ng-repeat="team in teams" ng-repeat="team in teams | filter:teamsFilter">
      <div>
        <style>
          .collapse-content {
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #dedede;
          }
        </style>

        <paper-card heading="{{ team.name }}">

           <div class="card-content">Some content</div>
           <div class="card-actions">
              <paper-button>Some action</paper-button>
           </div>
        </paper-card>       

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

//--------------------------- HTML -------------

I am using ng-polymer-element module,

I have the below code in my application app.js

```
    angular.module('ng-polymer-elements').constant('$ngPolymerMappings', {
      paperCard: {
            ngModel: function property(element) {
              return element.hasAttribute('multi') ? 'selectedValues' : 'selected';
            },
            ngHeading: '=heading'
        }
    });

window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady ', function() {
  angular.bootstrap(wrap(document), ['myApp']);
});
```

The Card header is coming fine but the binding variable is also displaying inside the card.

[image]

I inspect the HTML in the browser, i could see the paper-material is added twice and the second one is showing the brackets as it is.

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that Angular is not loaded properly; therefore, it hasn't kicked in to evaluate the expressions in the braces. Please post your entire HTML page.

Comment: I updated the question, The header is coming fine it is displaying the desired value. I am not sure what i am missing.

Comment: This issue is only in Google Chrome, in IE-edge and Firefox its is working fine.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code, but from the behavior you describe, it sounds like Chrome is compiling it differently from the other browsers. I think you probably have already checked the debugger for errors, but if not, I'd obviously suggest that. Also, just for grins, I'd try adding a semi-colon at the end of this line: ngHeading: '=heading'